# Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\mysql\CRUD\resources\views\Admin\Form User\index.blade.php)

Tags: model-view-controller, crud, php-7, laravel-7

Please help me. I'm new to Laravel.
I'm trying to view data from my table but it shows this error. I already defined the model in the controller. I put my index.blade.php inside the file.
These are my codes. I use Laravel 7

**app -> User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = "users";
}
```

**app -> Http -> Controllers -> AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

public function user(Request $request){

        return view('Admin/Form User/index');
}

public function show()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('index', ['index' => $users]);
    }

}
```

**routes -> web.php**

```
Route::get('/Admin/Form User/index', 'AdminController@user');
Route::get('/index', 'AdminController@show');
```

**resources -> views -> main.blade.php**

```
<a href="Admin/Form User/index" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Form User</a>
```

**resources -> views -> Admin -> Form User -> index.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Class</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Option</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($users as $u)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $u->class }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->name }}</td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <a>Edit</a>
                                    <a>Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to Passing your object in AdminController in this way,

```
 public function show()
        {
            $users = User::all();
            return view('index')->with('users', $users);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works now because I edited in AdminController with this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to using this way in your User model file. I think it will be work

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class User extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'class',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for fast respond. I already changed it in User.php with this but still didn't work. My error in Laravel shows this in line of resources -> views -> Admin -> Form User -> index.blade.php  :

@foreach($users as $u)